# 0,1の可変長フラグデータを扱う際のDBのデータ型について

Tags: c#, oracle

0,1の可変長データ（例：00000001、10000000001）をOracleDBの一つのカラムで管理したい場合のデータ型は何が適切でしょうか？
現状NUMBER型で設計していたのですが、可変長データを管理できないのではと考えております。
VARCHAR2で最大ビット数のサイズを確保して管理するのが良いでしょうか。最大ビットサイズは50ビットを想定しています。

プログラムは、C#でOracleは19cになります。

Comment: 「最大ビット数はどのぐらいを前提としているか」を明示すると回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: 1,0ならOracle19cで追加になったBITMAP関数群とBLOBを使うのが良いだろうと直感的に思ったのですが、50ビットなら文字列でも十分ですね。

Comment: 可変長でビットとのことですが、たとえば01と001を区別する必要があるのですか？たんに50ビットが収まる数値（C＃であればlongやulong）として管理するのはダメなのですか？

Comment: 01と001は区別する必要があります。ビットサイズと0001等の文字列で管理するのが適当と考えております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. '0'と'1'だけを使う10進数として管理する場合
   　NUMBER型の最大精度は38のため、50桁の2進数('0'と'1'だけを使う10進数)はNUMBER型で管理できないと思います。
   　VARCHAR2を使うことになるでしょう。
2. INPUTの2進数のデータを10進数に変換して管理する場合
   　「領域サイズの面で有利なのは、NUMBERまたはVARCHAR2のどちらなのか」は、モデルを作って実際に計測してみないと、どちらが有利かを言い切れません。
   　平均ビット数が小さい場合はVARCHAR2の方が有利な気もしますが、行数が多くないと、有意な差は出て来ないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

DBの型はデータに対してネイティブな型にするのが基本です。

> 0,1の可変長データ（例：00000001、10000000001)

これだけを読むと前置`0`に意味があるデータのように見えますが、そうすると

> 現状NUMBER型で設計

これでは前置`0`が保存されません。

入力データが何か、DB上やそれを読み込むプログラム側でデータがどう扱われるのか、が定義できていないのだと思います。

数値演算(ビット演算含む)が必要なのに文字列型にするとか、数値としては意味が無い前置`0`を扱わないといけないのに数値型にするとかしてしまうと、いちいちキャストするとか、ビット長を別カラムに保存するとか余計な処理が必要になります。